# 13.04 launcher and menu bar disappeared

Tags: unity, 13.04, launcher

Last night I downloaded python 3.3 and idle. I turned it on today and the launcher and menu bar disappeared. It didn't even ask for my password and all I see is my desktop. I tried finding answers from many places: [Launcher, top Panel, and window decorations missing after 12.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128676/launcher-and-window-menu-bar-missing-after-12-04-upgrade), [Unity has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256591/unity-has-disappeared), and [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration). But they all did not help and I do not know what to do. I tried `unity --reset` many times and it says reset option is now deprecated. I am not sure if this means anything but sometimes there are internal errors and when I try to show the details some directory which includes /bin. comes out and nothing else. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I happened once with me. My problem was a driver error. I uninstalled manually all the proprietary Nvidia drivers, than booted. It was enough to proceed to reinstall them.

Comment: Sorry but I am not really great with computers. Can you explain what you did?

Answer (score 0):

I followed these instruction and my menu bar is back: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/how-to-enable-new-kde-410-appmenu-title.html